# GLSL loading core dumped

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am compiling [this project](https://github.com/dgpdec/course) on a linux machine. After fixing all the include and lib errors, I get a core dumped error. but if I comment out the initGLSL line, it runs well. The initGLSL function is given below.

```
void Viewer :: initGLSL( void )
{
   shader.loadVertex( "shaders/vertex.glsl" );
   shader.loadFragment( "shaders/fragment.glsl" );
}
```

vertex.glsl:

```
varying vec3 position;
varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{   
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;

   position = gl_Vertex.xyz;
   normal = gl_Normal.xyz; 
}
```

I don't know how to debug this program. How can I check if this error is because of the GLSL, or the loader function?

**---------------Thanks for your comment------------**

The load function:

```
void Shader::loadVertex( const char* filename )
{
   load( GL_VERTEX_SHADER, filename, vertexShader );
}

void Shader::loadFragment( const char* filename )
{
   load( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, filename, fragmentShader );
}


void Shader::load( GLenum shaderType, const char* filename, GLuint& shader )
// read vertex shader from GLSL source file, compile, and attach to program
{
   string source;

   if( !readSource( filename, source ))
   {
      return;
   }

   if( program == 0 )
   {
      program = glCreateProgram();
   }

   if( shader != 0 )
   {
      glDetachShader( program, shader );
   }

   shader = glCreateShader( shaderType );
   const char* source_c_str = source.c_str();
   glShaderSource( shader, 1, &(source_c_str), NULL );

   glCompileShader( shader );
   GLint compileStatus;
   glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus );

   if( compileStatus == GL_TRUE )
   {
      glAttachShader( program, shader );
      linked = false;
   }
   else
   {
      GLsizei maxLength = 0;
      glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength );

      if( maxLength > 0 )
      {
         GLchar* infoLog = new char[ maxLength ];
         GLsizei length;

         glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, maxLength, &length, infoLog );

         cerr << "GLSL Error: " << infoLog << endl;

         delete[] infoLog;
      }
   }
}
```

and when I tried debugging with gdb, I get the msg:

```
(gdb) p (filename)
$1 = 0x482e41 "shaders/vertex.glsl"
(gdb) n
77        if( program == 0 )
(gdb) n
79           program = glCreateProgram();
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: You usually get a core dump when the application unsually terminates - possibly due to an access violation, or some uncaught signal or an abort due to an unhandled exception in C++. If your application crashes during shader, it is most likely due to a bug in your current driver. Syntax errors in a GLSL shader should *never* lead to program termination.

Comment: Show the implementation of `loadVertex (...)` if you can. I suspect you have not loaded the appropriate GLSL functions using `glXGetProcAddress (...)` or an appropriate extension wrangling library. A debugger would tell you this immediately though, and it is a skill you need to pickup at some point. Since it is trivial to produce this crash you will not have to learn any elaborate syntax to use something like `gdb`; just one or two commands.

Comment: @thokra a syntax error and many other things can definitely (but agreed, *should* never) lead to program termination. I have received many segfaults (in glCompileShader and glLinkProgram) from new GL features, writing code GLSL doesn't expect, long loops, branching, unrolling large amounts of code. These are clearly driver bugs, but they can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you definitely created an OpenGL context before calling `shader.load*`?

E.g. one of these, if you're using the corresponding library:

```
glutInit
glutCreateWindow

glfwInit
glfwCreateWindow

SDL_init 
SDL_CreateWindow
SDL_GL_CreateContext
```

I don't have much experience with this, but some GL functions aren't linked at runtime by default - `glCreateProgram` may still be `NULL` after creating a context. I use `GLEW` to do this for me (`glewInit()`), but [there are other ways](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: actully, I am using glew, the project itself doesn't contain glew, but on my platform, I find that many functions exist only on glew.h,so you mean I should add glewInit() before glCreatProgram?

Comment: @tintin yes. glew.h will provide some declarations but `glewInit` is needed to link the function pointers at runtime. You can check `glCreateProgram == NULL` dynamically too.